# How to get multiple return value from php by javaScript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my javaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IMDB').click(function() {  
       var MovieID = $('#MovieID').val();

       $.post('action/action.php', { url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+MovieID
+"?append_to_response=credits,images&api_key=myapikey" }, function(data) {
           $("#test").html(data);
       });
    });
});
```

When I click the button I get imdb id from my input field which I inserted
then I get the actual result from php. this is my php code.

```
<?php 
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $url2 = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($url2, true); //This will convert it to an array
    $title = $json['original_title'];
    $imdb = $json['imdb_id'];

    echo $title;
    echo $imdb;

    return true;

?>
```

But I get result like this :

> Batman: The Killing Jokett4853102

One is movie title and another is imdb id in same html tage. but I want to display my each result in each html tag like this :

```
$("#test").html(data); // result 1  -- movie title
$("#test2").html(data); // result 2 --- imdb id
```

Please help me how to get multiple value?

Comment: `echo json_encode(array($title, $imdb));` then use the object returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would probably be easiest just to output the entire JSON structure and work with that in Javascript, but if you just want the title and id, change your individual `echo` calls to one with a hash:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
  'title' => $title,
  'id' => $imdb
));
```

Then you can reference them in your javascript using:

```
var id = data.id;
var title = data.title;
```

Comment: OP: This is the best answer.  I recommend using this as a jumping-off point.

Comment: wow thanks a lot @Rob M . perfect answer thank you so much :) :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply return an array instead of separated values :

```
return json_encode([$title,$imdb]);
```

Then in your js parse the returned data and pluck the attributes you want from it :

```
data = JSON.parse(data);

$("#test").html(data[0]); 
$("#test2").html(data[1]);
```

Or you could add `json` to the `$.post` request the you don't have to parse the returned data :

```
$.post('action/action.php', { url: ...}, function(data) {
    $("#test").html(data[0]); 
    $("#test2").html(data[1]);
}, "json");
//__^^^^__
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it returns only one word :( first letter of movie title